# Cordova Android: distinguish internal SD card from external USB drive

Tags: android, cordova

I have a Cordova app on Android (v5 through 9) collecting data in remote Africa. The data is regularly dumped onto a USB drive. The problem is that on some devices, it is very hard to distinguish the internal SD card from the external USB stick.

We are currently using `cordova-plugin-removable-storage` and doing a `getMountInfo()`. On Android 6+, this gives paths like /storage/1234-567F and we can't know where it's backing up to.

The getMountInfo() function is actually reading `/proc/self/mountinfo` that, in my case gives:

```
136 33 0:20 / /storage/emulated rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime master:23 - sdcardfs /data/media rw,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,reserved=100MB
1653 33 0:22 / /storage/CF7E-647E rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime master:25 - sdcardfs /mnt/media_rw/CF7E-647E rw,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,mask=6,reserved=100MB
1992 33 0:23 / /storage/7637-1319 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime master:27 - sdcardfs /mnt/media_rw/7637-1319 rw,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,mask=6,reserved=100MB
```

CF7E-647E is my internal SD card and 7637-1319 is the USB drive. As you can see, there is no useful way to distinguish them.

Any suggestion on how I could guess on which devices I should write my backup ?

Comment: Isnt it always the second one? And using StorageVolumes it would be the third.

Comment: @blackapps You're right, taking the last external storage works. It feels dirty but at least it solves my issue, for now.

Comment: @blackapps Please turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it so you get the karma you deserve.